# create array which is filtered from array of dictionary with the array as a input

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have one dictionary and one array as shown below

**Dictionary :**

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "ctgid": "1",
            "catename": "tow"
        },
        {
            "ctgid": "2",
            "catename": "towrequest"
        },
        {
            "ctgid": "3",
            "catename": "electrical"
        },
        {
            "ctgid": "5",
            "catename": "plumber"
        },
        {
            "ctgid": "6",
            "catename": "maintenance"
        },
        {
            "ctgid": "7",
            "catename": "home"
        },
        {
            "ctgid": "8",
            "catename": "computer"
        },
        {
            "ctgid": "9",
            "catename": "1q2w"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Array of catename:**

```
(
tow,
towrequest,
plumber
)
```

There is a list of catename in Array.From above dictionary I want to create the array of ctgid related to catename in above array.

So my final output should be :

**Array of catgid :**

```
(
1,
2,
5
)
```

**Note : I can do it with loop , but I don't want to use any loop.**

Comment: why don't you want to use a loop?

Comment: what's the condition, you'r looking at ?

Comment: because I want efficient code , loop will consume lots of time.

Comment: I didn't understand your question @kumar

Comment: How is a loop not efficient?

Comment: I have lots of data to filter , its good if I find any options like NSPredicate which is the efficient way to filter the data from NSDictionary.

Comment: I search it But I can't find any thing about it.

Comment: How do you expect to find objects in array without using a loop? There is no other way to find array objects. If you want more efficiency, use a better data structure. Your data is far from optimized for what you need to accomplish.

Comment: it's not possible without loop

Comment: why its not possible without loop check my answer for filtering it Using NSPredicate

Comment: @CoolMonster You do realize that the implementation of the predicate will probably use a loop and will likely be less efficient than if a purpose-built, loop-based solution was written.

Comment: I don't know much about efficiency with the use of NSPredicate but 2 lines code is better than 10 lines of code !!!

Comment: @rmaddy,CoolMonster thanks to all for share your knowledge. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested , but hopefully this is it .

```
NSMutableArray *arrCatID = [NSmutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *instance in myDictionary){ // myDictionary is the values of "Value"
         NSString *content = [instance objectForKey:@"catename"];
        for (NSString *catName in stringArray) { // stringArray --> has already the CatNAmes with you 
           if (catName == content) {
             [arrCatID addObject:[instance objectForKey:@"ctgid"];
           break;
          }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer friend but, I already tried it and I want to do it without any loop if possible

Comment: How come it possible, without going through the Dictionary. we should compare with your dynamic content right ?

Comment: Ok.I am looking for something like NSPredicate. If I can't find anything,for loop will be a final option .

Answer (score 4):

```
//Json data
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"value\":[{\"ctgid\":\"1\",\"catename\":\"tow\"},{\"ctgid\":\"2\",\"catename\":\"towrequest\"},{\"ctgid\":\"3\",\"catename\":\"electrical\"},{\"ctgid\":\"5\",\"catename\":\"plumber\"},{\"ctgid\":\"6\",\"catename\":\"maintenance\"},{\"ctgid\":\"7\",\"catename\":\"home\"},{\"ctgid\":\"8\",\"catename\":\"computer\"},{\"ctgid\":\"9\",\"catename\":\"1q2w\"}]}";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//Converting the data into NSDictionary
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

//Get the array of objects
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"value" ]];

//Category filter names
NSArray *filteCatename = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tow",@"towrequest",@"plumber",nil];
//NSPreicate to filter the array using "in" constrain
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(catename in %@)", filteCatename]];
```

You can use `NSPredicate` to filter the `NSArray` directly without loop.

Comment: One of the requirements was to get the results in the same order as the strings in the list. It's unlikely that using this predicate ensures that will happen.

Comment: yup , It's in the same order.

Comment: oops sorry, you are right it's not in order but no worries , I don't want it in order.

Answer (score 2):

it is too late, though i put an answer hope this could help ..

```
   [dictArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { //dictArray is an array contains your "value" 
       if([arrCatename containsObject:[obj objectForKey:@"catename"]]) //arrCatename is array contains catename list
        {
          [arrCatid addObject:[obj objectForKey:@"ctgid"]]; //arrCatid is the result
        }
   }];

  NSLog(@"%@",arrCatid.description);
```